# ag-Grid Print functionality - Angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have implemented ag-Grid by using angular in my project successfully. Now trying to print ag-Grid data through following official ag-Grid doc https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-for-print/ .

I'm calling that print functionality method under onCellDoubleClicked() method. While double click a cell, ag-grid data print window should open. But I'm getting error like 'ERROR TypeError: l.setDomLayout is not a function'.

This is the way I've created method.

```js
onCellDoubleClicked($event) { 
var gridApi = this.gridApi; 
this.setPrinterFriendly(gridApi); 
setTimeout(function() { 
print(); 
this.setNormal(gridApi); 
}, 2000); 
} 
setPrinterFriendly(api) { 
var eGridDiv = document.querySelector(".my-grid"); 
this.style.width = ""; 
this.style.height = ""; 
api.setDomLayout("print"); 
} 
setNormal(api) { 
var eGridDiv = document.querySelector(".my-grid"); 
this.style.width = "600px"; 
this.style.height = "200px"; 
api.setDomLayout(null); 
}
```

Any one having idea please let me know, Is any thing I did wrong or correct approach. Thanks in advance.

This is the error:

[image]

Comment: You are passing "gridApi" to "setPrinterFriendly()" & "setNormal()" functions... what happens if you don't pass anything to these functions and instead of `api.setDomLayout("print");`, you do `this.gridApi.setDomLayout("print");` ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Yeah I've changed like this but no use. Still getting same error like 'ERROR TypeError: this.gridApi.setDomLayout is not a function'

Comment: If you put up a minimal stackblitz, someone will surely help

Comment: not sure if you solved the issue already, but please check your ag-grid version. Their document does not mention what version this setDomLayout API applies to, but it seems added after [v19](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/b19.1.4/dist/lib/gridApi.d.ts).

Comment: @wctiger Yes problem got solved..yes you are correct which I was using v18, after upgrading to latest version problem got solved.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tried `this.gridApi.setDomLayout` and still get 'this.gridApi.setDomLayout is not a function error', I guess `this.gridApi` is undefined. So add this in your JavaScript file.

```
onGridReady(params) {
   this.gridApi = params.api;
}
```

And this attribute

```
(gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
```

inside the `<ag-grid-angular>` tag

Comment: Could you post the complete code here so that it can be debugged.